# How can I store the SOAP xml request in Clob field Oracle in ESQL IBM Integration BUS

Tags: esb, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm trying to store the Soap Input Request (Soap UI Request) in the database for log in ESQL Langage. I'm noob in ESQL .

My flow is Soap Input ==> Compute Node ==> Soap Reply .

I have no idea to do this. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still require this or have already found a solution, but thought i'd post anyway.

This is something that has been quite common in several places I have worked. The way we tended to achieve this was by casting the incoming message as a bitstream and then casting it as a character -

```
DECLARE blobInputMsg BLOB ASBITSTREAM(InputBody CCSID 1208 ENCODING 546);
DECLARE charInputMsg CHAR CAST(blobInputMsg AS CHARACTER CCSID 1208 ENCODING 546);
```

The CCSID and ENCODING should be taken from the incoming message e.g. InputProperties.CodedCharSetId and InputProperties.Encoding, or defaulted to values suitable for your interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at Monitoring. Do the step by step stuff outlined here.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/546b8634-f33d-4ed5-834e-e7411faffc7a/entry/auditing_and_logging_messages_using_events_in_ibm_integration_bus_message_broker?lang=en

Be careful with the subscription in MQ as things get concatenated. Use MQExplorer to check your subscription including topic after you've defined it.

Also make sure you run the IIB queue definition scripts as per the install instructions for your version as one of the MQSC commands defines the topic.

Use a separate flow to write the events to your DB. Note in this day and age on Unix systems I'd probably write them to syslog and use ELK or Splunk